# Iphone 6S won't connect a specific WiFi network

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I've got a new iPhone 6S, however, the phone simply will not connect to my home's WiFi access point. It just says "Unable to join the network " - with no other information.

Annoyingly, I do have another access point for the same network, which does allow it to connect just fine. I also have another iPhone 6S, and that has no problems connecting either access point; which leads to me conclude there should be nothing wrong with the WiFi settings.

- I have tried disconnecting the other iPhone whilst connecting with the new one.
- I have tried restarting the router
- I have tried updating the router firmware
- I have tried restarting the phone
- I have tried resetting all of phones' network settings
- The phone has the latest firmware available to it

Unfortunately iOS doesn't give me any sort of logs as to why it couldn't connect and nothing is appearing in my router's logs.

I can't pin-point whether the iPhone or the router is defective, but I need to return the iPhone if it is. Any advice on either getting this working or diagnosing where the issue lies would be very helpful.

Comment: Can it join other WiFi networks, say at work or at somebody else's residence?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes, it can join other networks, hell it can even join another access point on the same network!

Comment: Didn't catch the access point mention in your post. If you can, see if the configuration details for the working WAP match the non-working WAP. Maybe there's a slight misconfiguration at play. You can also test by switching the ports the WAPs connect to on the router, assuming the WAPs are connected via Ethernet. Perhaps one of the router's ports is misconfigured.

Comment: I can check that. But the point is that the two access points are out of each others range.  The other iPhone 6S has no problem connecting to either of them. So I am not sure its a configuration issue. I will however try disconnecting everything from main WAP/Router so it should *just* be the new iPhone trying to connect.

Comment: What are the makes/models of the APs?  Are they updated to the latest firmware?  I’ve had experience with “consumer grade” gear that had [similar issues to yours](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305233/119271).